# Firebase authentication with custom redirect domain doesn't support TLS

Tags: firebase, https, firebase-authentication

I've followed the directions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login#customizing-the-redirect-domain-for-twitter-sign-in) to change the redirect domain during authentication.

Everything works fine (the redirect and the authentication) except that I don't have https support for the added custom domain. I'm assuming this is because the certificate from the firebase host doesn't match my custom domain. Is there something missing that I should be doing to support HTTPS on this custom redirect domain?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have certificate for your custom domain, use Firebase Hosting for your Firebase Authentication to have HTTPS support for your custom domain. Here is the instruction from [my own StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218777/firebase-auth-customized-redirect-domain-prompts-neterr-cert-common-name-inv):

1. In your Firebase project console, click 'Hosting' on the side menu.
2. When 'Set up hosting' pop-up appears, click 'Continue'. Then click 'Finish'.
3. In Hosting page, click 'Connect domain'.
4. When 'Connect domain' pop-up appears, enter `auth.your-custom-domain.com`. Then click 'Redirect `auth.your-custom-domain.com` to an existing website' checkbox. Then enter `your-app-123.firebaseapp.com`. Then click 'Continue'.
5. When 'Add the TXT records below to your DNS provider to verify you own `your-custom-domain.com`' pop-up appears, follow the instruction. And click 'Verify'. (Verifying may take some minutes). Then click 'Finish'.