# POST request error - net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to send a `POST request` for the react app hosted on firebase to the API built using `express.js` and `firebase` cloud functions.

when I try to send a request it fails with an error message:

```
POST "Request URL" net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

when I searched for the error I came to know (maybe) that this issue is related to the `SSL` certificate. I am not using any custom domain both the URL of API and web app is provided by `firebase` and have the `SSL certificate`.

Here's the error image:

[image]

The API works fine when tested with the postman.

Also, the error is the same for both the localhost and the URL provided by the firebase.
PS: I am using Axios to send the post request.

Please help!! any hint will be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Auth - customized redirect domain prompts NET::ERR\_CERT\_COMMON\_NAME\_INVALID warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218777/firebase-auth-customized-redirect-domain-prompts-neterr-cert-common-name-inv)

Comment: can you add the code that you are using to hit the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you manually setting the Cloud Function URL? That `www` at the beginning should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

As well, The `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error happens when the browser fails to verify a website’s [SSL certificate](https://www.kaspersky.com/resource-center/definitions/what-is-a-ssl-certificate) and is therefore unable to establish a secure connection. This issue usually occurs due to misconfiguration of the certificate on a server.
Kindly consider review your Backend Server Configurations too.

Answer (score 0):

For local testing...

I'm able to go the server address using https (on localhost but with a different host name address resolved in /etc/hosts). I get a security warning in Chrome when visiting the site using https. If I tell Chrome to go to the site anyway (override the warning), I can then make API calls to the same address.